# sanitizing content from open(url).read

Tags: ruby, text, sanitization

I am using Ruby to open a URL and read its content. The content type of the file I am reading is 'text/plain'.

The issue is that this contains some characters which I want to escape. For example, one of the characters that is coming up in the plain text is "\240" which is ASCII for a hyphen.

I am curious how this is being generated, because I don't see a hyphen anywhere in the text. Yet it exists invisibly and "\240" shows up when I use `puts` to print the text in the console.

Second of all, how do I escape such instances of weird characters? Ideally, I want to escape all characters which are of the form "\[some number]". I am using

```
"\240".gsub(Regexp.new("\\\d+"),"")
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Are there more traditional ways of sanitizing plain text content read from opening a URL?

Comment: A hyphen is not "\240". Hyphen is a lower-ASCII character, `45.chr #=> "-"`. You are seeing upper-bit characters.

Comment: How are you opening the URL? Show the URL and some sample code. Both Net::HTTP and Open::URI let you look at the content encoding to see what character set the server thinks the document is. The problem is the server can be wrong but it's your starting point. You can do a `HEAD` request to find the encoding then tell Ruby to use that when you receive the actual body. That should help avoid the characters that are being misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a play with this, I found the following regular expression which does the trick for me:

```
str.gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check on the character set of the text that's getting returned.  It could be UTF-8, which frequently has characters that high.  Ruby 1.9 has great support for character sets and switching between them.  I've used `str.encode("US-ASCII", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")` to force a string to standard ASCII, replacing any odd characters with a `?`.

Comment: I like this answer and will plan to use this approach after migrating to Ruby 1.9. Thanks!